# AWS Cloud formation plus auto scaling

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, autoscaling, amazon-cloudformation

I have created a cloud formation script to launch two instances, attach a volume on startup, and setup a load balancer. Now I am looking at setting up auto scaling and I am confused by the launch config. Does that need to basically include everything dealing with instance creation that my cloud formation script does?

Or is it possible to have the as-create-auto-scaling-group --launch-configuration tie into the cloudformation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer.

When you use a cloud formation script by default it in fact does create a launch configuration.  I just didn't notice it because I didn't see `as-describe-launch-configs` in the docs.

So after running that I found the created launch config and then went on with my `as-create-auto-scaling-group` commands using the existing launch config.

All seems to be good to go now. Sorry it was something so simple I overlooked and hopefully this will help the next person with this question. :-)